# how to use onSubmit in react-router while onSubmit checks the details in the form and if it's correct he pass with Link="" to another component

Tags: react-router

I'm trying to use onSubmit in the form, I wand it to check the details in the form and according to the details to decide if I want to pass to another component with Link in react-router how can I do that, how to write the Link (and it will pass only when I want in the onSubmit function)?
this is my routing-code:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import LogIn from "./components/LogIn";
import HomePage from "./HomePage";
import Todos from "./components/Todos";
import Albums from "./components/Albums";
import Info from "./components/Info";
import Posts from "./components/Posts";
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" pelement={<HomePage />} />
          <Route path="/login" element={<LogIn />} />
          <Route path="/todos" element={<Todos />} />
          <Route path="/info" element={<Info />} />
          <Route path="/albums" element={<Albums />} />
          <Route path="/posts" element={<Posts />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and I want that when I will click on the submit here(down- in the log in component) it will control on the Link="/" that will happen only if onSubmit decide

```
import { FormEventHandler } from "react";
function LogIn() {
  const [inputField, setInputField] = useState({
    user_name: "",
    password: "",
  });

  const inputChange = (e) => {
     e.preventDefault();
    setInputField((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    }));
  };

  const submitButton = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(**the details in the form are correct**) 
        **add the details to local storage and pass to home page with:<Link to="/"></Link>**
    else
        alert("details are not correct");
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={submitButton}>
      <label>Enter you user name</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="user_name"
        onChange={inputChange}
        placeholder="Your user name"
        value={inputField.user_name}
      />
      <br />
      <label>Enter you password</label>
      <input
        type="password"
        name="password"
        onChange={inputChange}
        placeholder="Your password"
        value={inputField.password}
      />
      <br />
        <button type="submit" >Log In</button>
    </form>
  );
}

export default LogIn;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't return a `Link` component in a callback like this and expect it to be rendered and do anything in the DOM. In callbacks you will need to issue an imperative navigation action using the `navigate` function.

Example:

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

function LogIn() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  ...

  const submitButton = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (**the details in the form are correct**) {
      // add the details to local storage 
      localStorage.setItem("details", details);
      // and pass to home page
      navigate("/", { state: { details } });
    } else {
      alert("details are not correct");
    }
  };

  ...
```